# How to verify if a binding scoped to a viewmodel is working? ie. How to know if Hilt is truly working?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I just created a simple Hilt Module that is installed in ViewModelComponent, and created a provides method for a dummy object that I am using in an Activity (through the viewmodel), and I want to know if the scoping is indeed working, How do I find out? Everything compiles and runs correctly. No issues there.

Comment: Put a breakpoint whenever in the Activity and look at the object created as rotating a device

Comment: Thanks I will try this. Follow up question how do I know if it get's destroyed when the viewmodel is destroyed? I'm assuming that is what viewmodelscoped means.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.